# CORS error when calling Firebase cloud function with httpsCallable()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am trying to call my Firebase cloud functions from my React client.

1. I am able to successfully call these functions using HTTP requests (as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)). This requires setting up a full Express app in the cloud function.
2. Now I am trying to call the cloud functions directly from my client using `httpsCallable()` (as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)). It appears that this method has a couple of advantages over calling over HTTP requests. However using this approach I am getting the following CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

How do I make this work? Is it worth the trouble? Is it really the preferred way?

Here's my cloud function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello from Firebase!');
});
```

Here's how I am calling it from my client:

```
const sayHello = async (): Promise<string> => {
    const helloWorld = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld');
    const result = await helloWorld();
    return result.data;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
const helloWorld = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('helloWorld');
const result = await helloWorld();
```

you are indeed calling a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), **but** by defining the called Function as follows

```
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {})
```

you are defining an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) **which is different**.

You should define your Cloud Function as a Callable one, as follows:

```
export const helloWorld =  = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return { response: 'Hello from Firebase!' };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Renaud! Your explanation about Callable Cloud functions vs. HTTPS Cloud functions was so much more clearer than the docs. I wish the docs had a overview section before these two sections explaining the difference and warning not to mix the two.